# I inflated a view 5 times, the view which was inflated had a EditText, now i have 5 EditText on the screen, how to get the text from those EditTexts

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, layout-inflater

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    EditText EditText1,EditText2,EditText3,EditText4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        EditText1 = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        EditText2 = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        EditText3 = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        EditText4 = findViewById(R.id.edittext);


        addChildLayout();
        addChildLayout();
        addChildLayout();
        addChildLayout();
    }

    public void addChildLayout(){

        LayoutInflater layoutInfralte=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       
        LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.infolayout);
      
        View view=layoutInfralte.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_layout, null);
        
        linearLayout.addView(view);

    }
}
```

how do I select the EditText, from all the four view and display them , any ideas? what can i do here ?

I want to get the data from each of the 4 EditTexts

Comment: correction its 4 times, my finger slipped and I didnt notice it

Comment: add your activity_main_layout.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    EditText EditText1,EditText2,EditText3,EditText4;
List<EditText> list=new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        EditText1 = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        EditText2 = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        EditText3 = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        EditText4 = findViewById(R.id.edittext);


        addChildLayout();
        addChildLayout();
        addChildLayout();
        addChildLayout();
    }

    public void addChildLayout(){

        LayoutInflater layoutInfralte=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       
        LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.infolayout);
      
        View view=layoutInfralte.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_layout, null);
EditText inflatededitText=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.youredittextid);
list.add(inflatededitText);
        
        linearLayout.addView(view);

    }
}
```

Now you can get any edittext like below

```
list.get(0).getText.toString
```

here 0 is position of edittext

if u need all edittext value then use for loop like this

```
for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
 Log.d("value","list.get(i).getText.toString");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.getText()` on each editText reference

Comment: there's only 1 EditText in the xml, it has only 1 id, 
EditText1 = findViewById(R.id.edittext) this is what wedo to select them
how to i select the other 3 inflated Edittext, they have the same id

Comment: You should have 4 edit texts in xml for that to work. If you want to inflate them programmatically make sure to assign them proper ids in order to get a reference using findViewById